# I keep getting the error argument type 'List <CartModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List <CartItem>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, state-management

I am new to flutter and taking  Maximillians flutter course, but i am stuck in passing an argument of list to a parameter of list type . I can't see anything wrong with the code so far.
The code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import '/providers/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:project_2/widgets/cart_item.dart';

class OrderItem {
  final String id;
  final double amount;
  final List<CartItem> products;
  final DateTime dateTime;

  OrderItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.amount,
    required this.products,
    required this.dateTime,
  });
}

class Orders with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<OrderItem> _orders = [];

  List<OrderItem> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }

  void addOrder(List<CartItem> cartProducts, double total) {
    _orders.insert(
      0,
      OrderItem(
        id: DateTime.now().toString(),
        amount: total,
        dateTime: DateTime.now(),
        products: cartProducts,
      ),
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The provider class above is used in the screen where i get the error. This is shown below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/providers/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:project_2/providers/order_provider.dart';

import '/widgets/cart_item.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CartScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const cartRoute = '/Cart Screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cartvalues = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cart Screen'),
        elevation: 0.5,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Total',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Chip(
                    label: Text(
                        '\$${cartvalues.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13)),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false).addOrder(
                        cartvalues.items.values.toList(),
                        cartvalues.totalAmount,
                      );
                      cartvalues.clear();
                    },
                    child: Text('Order'),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cartvalues.itemCount,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => CartItem(
                cartvalues.items.keys.toList()[index],
                cartvalues.items.values.toList()[index].id,
                cartvalues.items.values.toList()[index].price,
                cartvalues.items.values.toList()[index].quantity,
                cartvalues.items.values.toList()[index].title,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The cart Item widget code is also shown below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:project_2/providers/cart_provider.dart';

class CartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String productId;
  final String id;
  final double price;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;

  CartItem(
    this.productId,
    this.id,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.title,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
      background: Container(
        child: Icon(Icons.delete),  
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 4,)
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        Provider.of<CartProvider>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 4,),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            child: FittedBox(child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('\$$price'),
            ))
          ),
          title: Text(title),
          subtitle: Text('${(price * quantity).toStringAsFixed(2)}'),
          trailing: Text('${quantity}x'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro you should avoid using multiple providers. if your app is too big and you can split it into two or more Modules (Parts), then you can use multiple providers. else just declate a class provider for the whole app and use it. also, we don't use ChangeNotifier for models. I can't see a cartProvider class in your questions, please give us more insight into your problem.

Comment: I'd have to share the whole code, and it's quite large. Is there anyway I can do this more effectively?

Comment: @OlabanjoOlakunori don't share the whole code, just add `CartProvider` class code

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it, @iliyass comment was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Bro You can use just CartItem instead using CartModel in your cart Provider,
don't use your CartModel

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the '../providers/cart.dart' file uses it's proprietary class CartItem.

If you use lint to add your import headers, it might imported the CartItem definition from wrong file (as it happened to me)

Check you headers used for the CartItem import.

Answer (score 0):

In your orders class import this

import './cart.dart';

and remove this
import 'package:project_2/widgets/cart_item.dart';
it would work now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).